# How can I using jquery to get a data from a function in aspx.cs in .net c# web application?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I using jquery to retrieve the data from the function in aspx.cs in .net c# web application?

Example:
if I have a function call  `public void getData(string serachValue)`. When the user type in the word in the textbox, it will use jquery to call getData() to return the result and show on the screen

Comment: Are you using MVC or WebForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make this function static and add webmethod attribute:

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string Confirm(int id)
    {
        // confirm entry

        return "Test Data";
    }
```

Then use ajax() jquery method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 $('.confirmBtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPageName.aspx/Confirm",
            data: '{"id":"' + 1 + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var returnData = data.d;


            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError.toString());
            },
            timeout: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
```

And the best article talking about this is there: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I tried, the above example, but this is not working for me, its go to the error part and Error: 'undefined' is null or not an object

Comment: @Jin: I edited it, try it now, and by the way this is just a dummy sample, the link at the end of my answer will give you more details and how to play with.

Comment: The same error is showing. Just wandering is url: should be "MyPageName.aspx/Confirm" or webserver file with .asmx?

Comment: do i need to declare the webservice in my .aspx file?

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net MVC you'd create a controller action which calls `getData()` and returns Json data, or a partial view.  In JQuery you'd then call that action using it's URL in `.load()`, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is in the code behind you can tag decorate it with [WebMethod]

```
[WebMethod]
public static void getData(string serachValue) { ... }
```

Check out this blog for the jquery call and JS you will need.
http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: the method must be a static method